# Templating Spirit X3 parser

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

In Boost Spirit QI it was easy to template the parser so that it could be instantiated for various attribute types.  It is unclear to me how to do this with X3.  Consider this stripped down version of the [roman numerals parser example](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/roman_numerals.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace parser {

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct numbers_ : x3::symbols<unsigned> {
    numbers_() {
        add
            ("I"    , 1)
            ("II"   , 2)
            ("III"  , 3)
            ("IV"   , 4)
            ("V"    , 5)
            ("VI"   , 6)
            ("VII"  , 7)
            ("VIII" , 8)
            ("IX"   , 9)
            ;
    }
} numbers;

x3::rule<class roman, unsigned> const roman = "roman";

auto init = [](auto &x) { x3::_val(x) = 0; };
auto add = [](auto &x) { x3::_val(x) += x3::_attr(x); };

auto const roman_def = x3::eps [init] >> numbers [add];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(roman);

}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "V";
    auto iter = input.begin();
    auto end = input.end();
    unsigned result;

    bool r = parse(iter, end, parser::roman, result);

    if (r && iter == end) {
        std::cout << "Success :) Result = " << result << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed :(\n";
    }
}
```

I'd like to template the parser on the attribute type which is currently hardcoded as `unsigned`.  My first guess was to replace

```
namespace parser {
// ...
}
```

with

```
template < typename int_t >
struct parser {
// ...
};
```

which is obviously too naïve.  How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In X3 there's not so much pain in combining parsers dynamically. So I'd write your sample as:

```
template <typename Attribute>
auto make_roman() {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    struct numbers_ : symbols<Attribute> {
        numbers_() { this-> add
            ("I", Attribute{1}) ("II", Attribute{2}) ("III", Attribute{3}) ("IV", Attribute{4})
            ("V", Attribute{5}) ("VI", Attribute{6}) ("VII", Attribute{7}) ("VIII", Attribute{8})
            ("IX", Attribute{9}) ;
        }
    } numbers;

    return rule<class roman, Attribute> {"roman"} = 
        eps        [([](auto &x) { _val(x) = 0; })] 
        >> numbers [([](auto &x) { _val(x) += _attr(x); })];
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08927fe343e61d00)</kbd>**

Comment: That looks much better than the annoying grammar structs in QI.  Thank you very much!

Comment: If `numbers` were static, could one avoid the type erasure in the return type?

Comment: @ildjarn Can you elaborate what you mean by that? There's no type erasure in this answer.

Comment: Isn't the `rule<class roman, Attribute> {"roman"} =` part of the return statement type-erasure?

Comment: @ildjarn no. That's Spirit Qi you're thinking of